# SQL Server Percent Difference is Greater than Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structures:

table c_alert:

```
|dynamic|symbol|price_usd|
--------------------------
|5      |BTC   |13000   |
```

table c_current:

```
|symbol|price_usd|
------------------
|BTC   |13600   |
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT dbo.c_alert.symbol, dbo.c_alert.price_usd AS alert_price, dbo.c_current.price_usd AS current_price, (dbo.c_current.price_usd - dbo.c_alert.price_usd) * 100.0 / dbo.c_alert.price_usd AS pct_diff, dbo.c_alert.dynamic AS pct
FROM dbo.c_alert INNER JOIN
     dbo.c_current
     ON dbo.c_alert.symbol = dbo.c_current.symbol AND
        dbo.c_alert.dynamic > (dbo.c_current.price_usd - dbo.c_alert.price_usd) * 100.0 / dbo.c_alert.price_usd
```

Which returns this:

```
|symbol|alert_price|current_price|pct_diff|dynamic|
-----------------------------------------------
|BTC   |13000      |13613.3000   |4.7     |5   |
```

Not very strong with financial queries...Basically I would like to know when the price difference between alert_price and current_price are equal to or greater than value in the dynamic column as a boolean.  So where the difference is equal or greater than 5% show True, else False.  That dynamic value (integer) could change for each row in the c_alert table.  Hope someone can provide a solution to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the same percent difference term is required in multiple places in the query, I might go with using a CTE first, which calculates this term.  Then, do a straightforward query on the CTE to get the output you want.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t2.symbol,
        t2.dynamic,
        t2.price_usd AS alert_price,
        t1.price_usd AS current_price,
        100.0*(t1.price_usd - COALESCE(t2.price_usd, 0.0)) / t2.price_usd AS pct_diff
    FROM dbo.c_current t1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.c_alert t2
        ON t1.symbol = t2.symbol
)

SELECT
    symbol,
    alert_price,
    current_price,
    pct_diff,
    dynamic,
    CASE WHEN pct_diff > dynamic THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS result
FROM cte;
```

**Edit:**

The logic seems to be working in the demo below.  If you still have issues, then edit the demo and paste the link somewhere as a comment.

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, same problem as Gordon's if I enter 3 (dynamic) as the percentage, its returning false, 13k * 3% = 390 so 13.6k is greater than 13,390 so it should return true.

Comment: Edit your question and show us data.  My logic is correct as far I can tell.

Comment: Symbols are always available in both tables, as per the examples above (c_alert and c_current).

Comment: If you aren't comparing the percent difference against the dynamic value, then what comparison are you actually doing?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it correctly...13,000 * 3% = 13,390 so if the current price is 13,613 the difference being positive the query should return true.  However if the dynamic value is 5 we have 13,000 * 5% = 13,650 and current price is 13,613 (-37 difference) is false because the current price is a difference of just 4.7 %. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Still confused.  Can you write a formula for this, using exact column names?

Comment: @Rob LOL ... I didn't do anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use table aliases so your query is easier to write and to read.  Then just use a `case`:

```
SELECT a.symbol, a.price_usd AS alert_price,
       c.price_usd AS current_price,
       (c.price_usd - a.price_usd) * 100.0 / a.price_usd AS pct_diff,
       a.dynamic AS pct,
       (case when (a.price_usd - c.price_used) > a.dynamic
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as flag
FROM dbo.c_alert a INNER JOIN
     dbo.c_current c
     ON a.symbol = c.symbol AND
        a.dynamic > (c.price_usd - a.price_usd) * 100.0 / a.price_usd;
```

SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, so this uses a string.  You can use `0` and `1` instead.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I changed the dynamic to 3 and it returned no result, should have returned true?

Comment: @Rob . . . I might have misinterpreted the logic.